# Is it OK to patch/update the `status` field of a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an idea for providing some extra metadata about my Kubernetes clusters' tenants' pods by writing a controller that watches for certain cluster status data and then "tattoos" affected pods with extra data in the `status` field.  But I'm not sure if it's OK to write extra data into that field -- is there any official Kubernetes documentation that says whether 3rd party controllers may write to pods' status fields?  I haven't been able to find any.

This probably sounds a bit like an X-Y problem, so I will explain below why I would like to do this, and if you have a better suggestion for how to solve the problem, I'm all ears.

My team owns and operates a number of large, multi-tenant Kubernetes clusters for our company's developers.  We only own the Kubernetes environment, NOT the applications, and we have no influence at all over how developers choose to deploy their apps, aside from cluster-wide things like locking down developers into their own groups of namespaces, enforcing sane network policies between namespaces, that sort of thing.

We have a class of developers who, for reasons beyond the scope of this question, run "singleton" applications (single pod) in our Kubernetes clusters and thus their applications are disrupted when that single pod gets evicted from the node it's running on (generally due to our automated drain-patch-reboot mechanism for our cluster workers).  These developers have been complaining to us that the pod evictions, while expected as part of running in a Kubernetes environment, are troublesome because they happen at unexpected times.  They would like to have a chance to *plan* for these scheduled pod evictions so they can notify their customers, schedule their own maintenance during the same window, etc.

Now we could take the BOFH approach and just say, "sorry, you're not running a 12-factor app in Kubernetes, you get what you pay for" and send them packing.  But That's not going to endear ourselves to their executives, much less our CIO.  So we want to be "nice" and at least try to provide some kind of mechanism for these developers to predict and prepare for these events.  But we refuse to give up any of the platform automation we've worked so hard to implement.  Absolutely no "hand-holding" or manual scheduling of worker node patching to accommodate these singleton apps.

We already have implemented a system that applies labels to each worker node that indicates when each node is scheduled to go down for patching.  This helps some, but it's kind of awkward: tenants have to first look up which node their pod is running on, then look up that node to get an answer back.  They're asking for something more direct -- a query they can run that simply returns a list of their pods along with a timestamp indicating when that pod is next expected to be disrupted by planned maintenance activity.

One possible solution I've considered is to write a controller that performs the "node to pod" linking and then updates a field in the Pod spec (presumably under `status`) to provide this information.  Then our tenants can use a simple `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath=...` to return a list of pods and their expected-next-disruption timestamps.  This has the advantage of working entirely within the cluster's RBAC framework, so tenants can only inspect their own pods.  If I were to write this as an external API of some kind, I'd have to awkwardly re-implement the Kubernetes RBAC to ensure that tenants can only query their own pods and not be able to enumerate peer teams' pods from the same cluster.

Assuming it's kosher from a K8s machinery point of view to use the `status` field for this, I feel like it's the cleanest solution, hence my question.  But I haven't been able to find any authoritative documentation about the "proper use" or "acceptable use" of the pod `status` field.  I could achieve the same thing using labels or annotations, but to me this feels like it might get in the way -- for example, there may be developers who have very specific labels or annotations they use and expect, and for me to jam in a new one they're not expecting could break CI/CD processes or even cause downtime (remember, we have no control over the apps themselves, just the cluster).

Comment: I think adding an `annotation` is the right way to handle this. This is exactly what kubernetes itself does in some situations.

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to S.F. This question appears to be asking for a tech solution to a communication/relationship management problem. No reasonable dev-team can treat a Pod as a pet (in the cattle-pet metaphor) because that is 100% not how kubernetes thinks about the world. Nodes, and Pods, can fail or be evicted for a bazillion reasons, so the next question posted would be "the OOMKiller made my devs angry, how can I annotate things that are _going_ to be OOMKilled" and so forth

Comment: @mdaniel I already addressed this in my question:

Now we could take the BOFH approach and just say, "sorry, you're not running a 12-factor app in Kubernetes, you get what you pay for" and send them packing. But That's not going to endear ourselves to their executives, much less our CIO.